# Project wise create Provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I want to create multiple provisioning profiles from the same AppleID.

Example:

- Project 1 - Number of Added UDID is 3
- Project 2 - Number of Added UDID is 4
- Project 2 - Number of Added UDID is 1

How should I create multiple project wise provisioning profiles?

Currently I have one provisioning profile which has all the 20-25 UDIDs. But I want to create the different provsioning profiles or particular application.

Comment: You need to create multiple bundle identifiers and create provisional profiles for those identifiers. Then while adding devices, add to the corresponding profiles.

Comment: @ACB can u please give me the steps for this

Comment: Looks like you already got the answers. Are you facing any issues with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create APP IDs for each of your app. Follow [Creating and Configuring App IDs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH18-SW1)

Then create provisioning profile for each of your APP ID. Follow [Creating and Downloading Development Provisioning Profiles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles.html)

You can allow devices separately in each provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

First of all create APP ID then go to provisioning profile tab create new profile here choose your profile name and add APP ID which you have created as well as check the devices id's from list which you want to be use at last click on sbumit.thats all

Answer (score 0):

So create project wise app id and create distribution provision profile of every app id. Make tick mark of the device of every provisioning profile.

Like you can create app id "com.app.project1","com.app.project2"... corresponding distribution provision profile "project1adhocdistribution", "project2adhocdistribution"....